# How to pass a java object to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, websphere-portal

I have a serveresource method which is invoked on clicking a link. The serveresource method takes the input from the parameter that was passed and retrieves a row from the database. Now all the values in a row are in set using the mutator methods. I have everything in a java object. I need to pass this object to a jsp page to print the values of a single row on the jsp page. I am not sure how to handle that java object in the jsp page instead of setting each value as an attribute in the serveresource method. Need help from experts.. Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**

It was because I have an Ajax call and when I set values it is in a completely different life cycle which is causing the problem. I figured it out.

Comment: see the JSP Expression Language http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html.You will be able to get the value to JSP

Comment: sorry the link is broken..http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Answer (score 1):

You should defining the **java object as Bean in JSP**. 
The Bean in JSP can be defined using **< jsp:useBean..>** standard jsp tag. And **set and get property using < jsp:setProperty..> and < jsp:getProperty..>** standard jsp tags.

Refernces:

- [Use Bean](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/UseBean.shtml)
- [Using Beans in JSP. A brief introduction to JSP and Java Beans](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/usingbeansinjsp.shtml)
- [UseBean syntax](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm14.html)
- [< jsp:setProperty> and < jsp:getPropety> syntax](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm13.html#8856)

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is to add it to the `HttpServletRequest` object, thus:

```
MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
myBean.setValue("something);
myBean.setAnotherValue("something else");

// ... stuff ... 

request.setAttribute("myBean", MyBean);
```

This can be accessed from the jsp page using EL thus:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>${myBean.value}</td>
    <td>${myBean.anotherValue}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can bind with request object

```
In Servlet or JSP
request.setAttribute("strIdentifire", yourJavaObject);


In JSP
YourJavaObjectClass obj = (YourJavaObjectClass)request.getAttribute("strIdentifire");
```

Comment: Writing scriplets in JSP's is bad practise. Should avoid it.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202